# How can I get the position through the pan event in ionic2 or ionic3?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic2

So,everyone knows that we can add the code below to capture the pan event in ionic2:

```
(pan)='panEvent($event)'
```

but,I want to know how can I get the x, y coordinates of the points when I pan the screen? there is some documents about the structure of the $event,I guess througth the $event,we can get the x,y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the $event passed to get what you want.
The event object can be found [here](https://hammerjs.github.io/api/#event-object).

I used  the`center` property to get the coordinates. I don't know if it's the correct property because the description from HammerJS is somewhat vague. to get but it gives the correct value.

You can find a sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-m1kblq?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html).